# What is the best way in LINQ to sort 1000000 Records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sorting

I want to sort  and page 1,000,000 records with Linq. I don't know if the way I use to get the data or correct or not because the pages goes so slowly.

Here is my code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllProducts(int page, string SortColumn,string Name = null)
{
    const int PageSize = 4;
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    IEnumerable<Product> result = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
    {
        result = db.Products.OrderBy(SortColumn).AsEnumerable();

    }
    else
    {
        result = db.Products
            .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(Name))
            .OrderBy(SortColumn).AsEnumerable();
    }


    int NumberOfPages = result.Count();
    var begin = (page - 1) * PageSize;
    var data = result.Skip(begin).Take(PageSize).AsEnumerable();


    ProductPager myproduct = new ProductPager
    {
        ProductList = data,
        TotalRecords = NumberOfPages

    };
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myproduct);
    return response;


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are currently pulling all 1 million records out of your database into memory, and applying your `Skip()` and `Take()` to that collection. This is very expensive. Change your `IEnumerable<Product>` into an `IQueryable<Product>` and get rid of the calls to `.AsEnumerable()`.

Here's what I'd do:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAllProducts(int page, string sortColumn, string name = null)
{
    const int PageSize = 4;
    IQueryable<Product> query = db.Products;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(name));
    }

    int numberOfRecords = result.Count();
    var begin = (page - 1) * PageSize;
    var data = query.OrderBy(sortColumn)
        .Skip(begin).Take(PageSize)
        .ToList();

    ProductPager myproduct = new ProductPager
    {
        ProductList = data,
        TotalRecords = numberOfRecords 
    };
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myproduct);
}
```

#### What's Happening?

Entity Framework is a *LINQ Query Provider*. When you access `db.Products`, that's returning an object which implements `IQueryable<Product>` and `IEnumerable<Product>`. This gives you two sets of LINQ extension methods, many of which overlap each other (e.g. `Where()`, `Skip()`, `Take()`, `OrderBy()`, and `Count()`).

Calling the methods that pertain to `IQueryable<>`, will do one of two things:

1. For operations that don't require immediate evaluation (like `Where()`, and `OrderBy()`) no actual work is done in relation to the database: you just get another `IQueryable<>` that records the fact that you wanted to call a particular LINQ method with specific parameters.
2. For operations that require immediate evaluation (like `Count()`), a SQL Query will be issued representing the query that you've built up so far, and you'll retrieve the result that is needed. For example, SQL Server will actually count the necessary records, and return just a number, instead of returning individual records.

On the other hand, if you call the methods that pertain to `IEnumerable<>`, you produce an object that will (either immediately or when evaluated later) perform the original query (giving you all Products in the database) and then iterate over it to do things like filtering, skipping, taking, ordering, and counting.

Since `IQueryable<>` is *more specific* than `IEnumerable<>`, the `IQueryable<>` extension methods are typically invoked, unless you go out of your way to cast the result as an `IEnumerable<>` (which is what you've done in your code).

Comment: Shouldn't the `OrderBy` be before the `Skip` and `Take`?

Comment: Yes, yes it should. Good catch, guys.

Comment: @DavidG: I added an explanation. Anything else you think I should add?

Comment: Ah, that's brilliant - great answer.